# R: read CSV Column & write in another column

Tags: r

Looking for some suggestion in below:
Read Csv file column and merge row 1 with row3 as in expected output

CSV FIle:
Actual output:

```
Source: Google          
#                           
Category    Orders   Conversion Visits
Mobiles  50507      5.10%   994251
```

Expected Output:

```
Category    Orders   Conversion Visits  Source
Mobiles          12957    1.70%       748276    Google
```

Comment: Do  you have that `Row1:, Row2` strings in the file or just identifiers you added?

Comment: Its just identifiers..Its contains only source:Google(Col1,Col2)

Answer (score 0):

We can read it with `readLines`

```
lines <- readLines("yourfile.txt")
```

Extract the words from the first line using `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
v1 <- str_extract_all(lines[1], "\\w+")[[1]]
```

Read the 'lines' 3 to 4 as a data.frame with `read.table` and `cbind` with the 'v1'.

```
d1 <- read.table(text=lines[-(1:2)], header=TRUE)
cbind(d1, setNames(list(v1[2]), v1[1]))
#  Category Orders Conversion Visits Source
#1  Mobiles  50507      5.10% 994251 Google
```